# PostgreSQL: Transforming rows into columns when more than three columns are needed

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I have a table like the following one:

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------------+--+
| Section | Group | Level | Fulfillment |  |
+---------+-------+-------+-------------+--+
| A       | Y     |     1 | 82.2        |  |
| A       | Y     |     2 | 23.2        |  |
| A       | M     |     1 | 81.1        |  |
| A       | M     |     2 | 28.2        |  |
| B       | Y     |     1 | 89.1        |  |
| B       | Y     |     2 | 58.2        |  |
| B       | M     |     1 | 32.5        |  |
| B       | M     |     2 | 21.4        |  |
+---------+-------+-------+-------------+--+
```

And this would be my desired output:

```
+---------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
| Section | Group | Level1_Fulfillment | Level2_Fulfillment |
+---------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
| A       | Y     | 82.2               | 23.2               |
| A       | M     | 81.1               | 28.2               |
| B       | Y     | 89.1               | 58.2               |
| B       | M     | 32.5               | 21.4               |
+---------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Thus, for each section and group I'd like to obtain their percents of fulfillment for level 1 and level 2. To achieve this, I've tried crosstab(), but using this function returns me an error  ("The provided SQL must return 3 columns: rowid, category, and values.") because I'm using more than three columns (I need to maintain section and group as identifiers for each row). Is possible to use crosstab in this case?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find `crosstab()` unnecessary complicated to use and prefer conditional aggregation:

```
select section, 
       "group", 
       max(fulfillment) filter (where level = 1) as level_1,
       max(fulfillment) filter (where level = 2) as level_2
from the_table
group by section, "group"
order by section;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ab13bf752bdebb2ed895db80588da29f)

Comment: You are completely right, @a_horse_with_no_name. Using crosstab is unnecesarily complex to achieve my result. Your solution works like a charm and is easier to understand.